# how make wp include urls as https?

Tags: themes, css, https

i am doing migration of my website from http to https . now static files are coming from http schema . example

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://demo.com/news/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://demo.com/news/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
```

it should be

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://demo.com/news/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://demo.com/news/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
```

i added

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

to remove redirection because it load from aws cloud front . what i have to do to load all css/js from https ?

Comment: How did you do the migration exactly? Have you changed the URL's in the WordPress settings pages to switch from HTTP to HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you included these scripts on your website. Did you include them directly on your theme files (i.e. *footer.php, header.php*) or did you use *wp_enqueue_script* on your functions.php?

In the first case, you have to manually update these script URLs to https while please make sure you've updated your WordPress and Site Address to *https* on the latter.

Comment: In the first case you should definitely fix that and start using `wp_enqueue_script` ;)